# Assign Values to Text in specific column in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a CSV which contains over 2 million rows. One of the columns named "DEPARTMENTS" has 44 different unique types of text values. I wish to replace them by numbers:

- For instance DELI = 1
- Meat = 2
- and so on.

In every row under DEPARTMENT column wherever it displays DELI, I want this to be replaced by number 1 and for Meat 2 and so on.

I managed to find some code to identify all unique values and length

```
unique_v <- (unique(grouped$DEPARTMENT)
length (unique_v)
```

RESULTS

```
[1]                 AUTOMOTIVE      CHARITABLE CONT CHEF SHOPPE     CNTRL/STORE SUP
 [6] COSMETICS       COUP/STR & MFG  DAIRY DELI      DELI            DELI/SNACK BAR 
[11] DRUG GM         ELECT &PLUMBING FLORAL          FROZEN GROCERY  GARDEN CENTER  
[16] GM MERCH EXP    GRO BAKERY      GROCERY         HBC             HOUSEWARES     
[21] KIOSK-GAS       MEAT            MEAT-PCKGD      MEAT-WHSE       MISC SALES TRAN
[26] MISC. TRANS.    NUTRITION       PASTRY          PHARMACY SUPPLY PHOTO          
[31] PORK            POSTAL CENTER   PROD-WHS SALES  PRODUCE         RESTAURANT     
[36] RX              SALAD BAR       SEAFOOD         SEAFOOD-PCKGD   SPIRITS        
[41] TOYS            TRAVEL & LEISUR VIDEO           VIDEO RENTAL   
44 Levels:   AUTOMOTIVE CHARITABLE CONT CHEF SHOPPE CNTRL/STORE SUP ... VIDEO RENTAL
> length(unique_v)
[1] 44
```

If anyone can name me the function to use in order to achieve this, I would be grateful. I have had a look and wasn't able to find much. maybe I am looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Try `as.numeric(factor(grouped$DEPARTMENT, levels=yourlevels))`

Comment: hey @akrun do you mean by levels
z <- ("MEAT", "DELI")
levels(z) <- grouped$DEPARTMENT[1:44] ?

Comment: You can specify the levels arguments in the way you want the replacement elements to appear.  For example `as.numeric(factor(grouped$DEPARTMENT, levels=c('DELI', 'Meat',...)))`.  So, by converting to numeric, this will be replaced by `1,2, etc`

Comment: hey just going to be a little cheeky, if there a way I can automate this so the code automatically assigns a numeric value to each unique value. (saves me typing each level) they are 44 of them. (just curious)

Comment: You could use `levels=unique(grouped$DEPARTMENT)` if they are in the same order as you wanted.  Or if you need an alphabetic order `levels=sort(unique(grouped$DEPARTMENT))`.  Else, if you need it in some specific order, then you have to pass the levels manually

Comment: I have sorted them already so they all in alphabetic order, running the code now, will update shortly. Thank you

Comment: test <- as.numeric(factor(groupedData$DEPARTMENT, levels=unique(groupedData$DEPARTMENT)))

Comment: write.csv(test, file="groupedv6.csv,row.names=FALSE)

it doesn't print the new file with the changed values??

a new column has been created with X and all the values, the rest of the data has disappeared (maybe I forgot to mention about the other columns, in total I have 11 columns)

Comment: You created a vector `test`.  Instead of that you may need to create a new column in the `groupedData` or replace the old column DEPARTMENT by `groupedData$newColumn <- as.numeric(factor(...)` and then use `write.csv(groupedData, file=..)`

Comment: I wasn't able to replace the existing column, however it created a new column at the end, I guess I can just delete the old column. But it worked, thank you so much for all your help, really appreciated. @akrun

Comment: Yes, because the code is to create a new column :-).  If you need to replace the old one `groupedData$DEPARTMENT <- as.numeric(...`

Comment: I do apologise I just realised want I done, you're right sorry. I guess I am still learning :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we need to convert the "character" elements to "numeric", one option would be to convert to "factor" class, specify the `levels` and then coerce to "numeric" by `as.numeric`.  In the specific example, if we need to replace the "old" column elements with "numeric" elements

```
groupedData$DEPARTMENT <- as.numeric(factor(groupedData$DEPARTMENT,
                  levels=sort(unique(grouped$DEPARTMENT))))
```

Then, we can write the results back to file using `write.csv`